# Laravel returning UTCDateTime instead of Carbon instance. Why?

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel

I have a model that has the following in it:

```
protected $dates = ['created_at','modified_at','deleted_at', 'my_date'];
```

The same model is embedded in another document (using Mongo).

Now when I try to get the min and max dates in the model by doing:

```
 $minDate = $doctor->cases()->min('embedded_doc.my_date');
 $maxDate = $doctor->cases()->max('embedded_doc.my_date');
```

What I am getting are instances of UTCDateTime and not Carbon. The documentation states that if I list the date in the $dates array it would return Carbon instances. I am not clear. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is happening because when you run `min` or `max` query it returns the single value, not an object of the Model.

That's why it's not converted into Carbon.

You can also write your query as:

```
$doctor->cases()->orderBy('my_date')->select('my_date')->first()->my_date;
```

This will give the Carbon object.